# Sports.Stackexchange - don't we need actually two separate stacks for this?

Tags: discussion

Today I've discovered [sports.stackexchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com) - yet another wonderful beta from Area51.
It looks to me like that there is actually space for two stacks not one.

You see, the phrase "stack exchange site on sports" can be interpreted in the sense "questions for those, who like read sports column in newspapers, watch tv-translations or even gambling". 
Here is [the question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/772/why-does-messis-50th-goal-count-as-a-record) of this type:

> Last night, Messi scored his 50th goal of the season.
>
> Why is it considered a new goal-scoring record? Dixie Dean scored 60
>   goals for Everton in the FA First Division alone (he had 67 in total)
>   in the 1927-1928 football season

On the other hand, it can be interpreted as "questions on a specific kind of human activity I'm currently involved in".  Kinda programmers.stackexchange for sportsmen.

[Here is](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/941/how-can-i-improve-my-ball-handling) the question of "type B":

> I play football (soccer) for my community traveling team. Our usual
>   ball handling exercise is getting the ball around a course of cones.
>
> What other ways can I improve my ball handling abilities?

These topics are related, but nevertheless one can easily tell one from another.
Moreover, community of people who loves "type A" questions and community of people who love "typeB" questions are not that indistinguishable (checkout Homer Simpson, for example).
Moreover, it looks like these two sets of questions have the same cardinality, i.e roughly 50% of questions are specifically of type A, the same about type B. For me this is a great sign of  that these don't belong together.

Say, may be we need Sports.Stackexchange **and** Sportmen.Stackexchange? 
By the way, regarding the last one, there is also [Physical Fitness stack](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/physical-fitness) we should keep in mind.

So, discuss )

Comment: +1 sports interpretation vs. sports application, for example? I'm not recommending those as site names, but as for the idea in of itself.

Comment: There are a lot of sports - including, perhaps primarily, running - where figuring out the interrelationship of fan and participant is a big issue within the sport itself. So this is not a unique discussion to this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a much discussed topic in early beta.

Quite frankly, the answer from SEI was no, you will coexist and figure out an identity. We attempted things like a merge, or better lines of division with physical fitness. But that was met with a gentle rebuff.

As of now, the site is working out fairly well as is. The fan and the participant are, for the most part, coexisting peacefully, and getting reasonable answers to their question. As long as this continues I think two separate identities of this site will stay together (however haphazardly cloven they are).

Comment: well, if community is OK with it, I guess I can see no reasons to argue )